# SSMS 2012 - table designer doesn't show recently added fields

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-2012

I cant see in table designer fields created via SQL script.
If I add new field to designer it warns me about difference detections and lists all added fields via script

Is there any way table designer to display all table's fields no matter if created via designer or query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Close the designer window (not SSMS) without saving
- reopen it and it should offer to refresh, it will see the changes from your script.
- Once it has picked up all of the changes, save the  designer before making any more changes.

Comment: Indeed, this works. Is there any other option then restarting MS SSMS ? This is quite annoying... Im sure in older versions I didnt have to do that and all changes done by scrips were visible by designers...

Comment: I have clarified the answer, it is just the designer window /tab that you need to close not SSMS. Still at least you got there

Comment: Hi @Maciej, if this is OK now, can you set this question to answered?